# Field Length Validation for Desktop Application which has maximum 1000 characters

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, testcase

The character limit we are updating each field to will differ based on the information they are capturing. As a couple of examples, Company Name will be updated from 630 characters to 1000, and Address Lines will be updated from 40 characters to 60

Could you please let me know what would be valuable test cases for this requirement from UAT perspective?

Answer (score 10):

> User acceptance test (UAT) criteria (in agile software development)
>   are usually created by **business customers** and expressed in a business
>   domain language
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing

I don't think Field Length Validation has anything to do with **User** acceptance testing. Maybe the business should write their own tests.

Never the less here are some testing pointers and ideas:

Map how the data is used. Don't forget to test locations where the data is used, test the new length is used properly. For example in reports. E.g. don't only test that the input and storage works.

For example:

- Does the address still fit the plastic envelope window in traditional letters used for sending invoices?
- Are API based on this data still backward-compatible?

Make a shared [list of test heuristics](http://testobsessed.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/testheuristicscheatsheetv1.pdf) how your team should test input fields.

Personally, I don't like to limit input fields. Challenge why does it now go from 40 to 60? What is the chance next week it needs to be 80? I have seen street names/city names that are way longer than 60.

Company names of 1000 characters? You are making this stuff up, because company names are never so long, at least not that I can find. Maybe also test the requirements up-front, instead of after they are implemented.

Other reads:

- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34920/how-many-characters-should-typical-address-fields-allow-on-an-international-webs
- http://testobsessed.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/testheuristicscheatsheetv1.pdf

Comment: +1 Neils answer, as usual, is very helpful

Answer (score 2):

If character lengths are changing I would suggest boundary testing

For example I would consider testing:

- no chrs
- 1 chr
- 629 chrs
- 630 chrs
- 631 chrs
- 999 chrs
- 1000 chrs
- 1001 chrs
- 1002 chrs

I would retain the following as regression tests going forward:

- no chrs
- 1 chr
- 999 chrs
- 1000 chr
- 1001 chrs

Answer (score 2):

I would like to prefer the Equivalence and Boundary Value for each field.

Minimum,
Just above the minimum,
A nominal value,
Just below the maximum,
Maximum.

While providing the input, I hope application should consider spaces between the words should be a character

If it is non -required field check with NULL/EMPTY values and try to update some charters from the Edit screen

Answer (score 0):

When field lengths are updated, Boundary validation is most important as per the qa services

You can refer to the below **checkpoints** to validate the field length by entering characters:

> - More than the previous limit
> - Equivalent to the new limit
> - Less than the new limit
> - Make a check you are not able to exceed the new limit
> - Also, if the field can accept null values or not if permitted
> - Most important would be to check that you are **able to update the existing data** in the fields as per the **new field length**
> - After saving the 1000 character text -> make sure the UI works fine i.e 1000 character text does not overlap/distort other content on the
>     page